# Overriding Apply_gradients for custom distributed training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient, gradient-descent

I'm playing with an CNN architecture involving three identical networks that I train with non-overlapping datasets and then coordinate each iteration. Each weight is updated by averaging this weight with the corresponding weight in the other nest and then proportionally adding this weight's current gradient.

I'm using tensorflow 2.2.0 and keras, and I think I'm wanting to override apply_gradients to do it. My first question is Should I be overriding apply_gradients?

Secondly, I have a list of the parameters for each of the models. In apply_gradients, I have a list of gradients and the var_list that goes with it. The gradients are Tensors, and the parameters are Variables. Apply_gradients needs to return an Operation. How do I take a weighted sum (an average) of the parameter variables and then perform the standard Gradient descent, returning an Operation?

Here's my current (commented out) code for apply gradient taken out of my custom optimizer subclass:

```
def apply_gradients(self,
                    grads_and_vars,
                    name=None,
                    experimental_aggregate_gradients=True):
    # Formatting grads_and_vars
    grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    var_list = [v for (_, v) in grads_and_vars]

    with K.name_scope(self._name):
        with ops.init_scope():
            self._create_all_weights(var_list)

        if not grads_and_vars:
            return control_flow_ops.no_op()


        strategy = distribute_ctx.get_strategy()
        
        apply_state = self._prepare(var_list)
        
        #Formatting done

        #Here's the trouble spot, where I'm trying to update the vars

        #CDSGD
        grads, var_list = zip(*grads_and_vars)
        
        grads = list(grads)
        var_list = list(var_list)

        opsR = []
        
        l_r = self._get_hyper("learning_rate")
        for i in range(len(grads)):
            
            #base = var_list[i] * 0

            #for j in range(3):     # 3 Networks, agent_id is that particular network's id 0-2
            #    base += self.pi[j][self.agent_id] * parameters[j][i]    
            #parameters holds all the networks' parameters

            #var_list[i] = var_list[i].assign(base)
            
            opt1 = training_ops.resource_apply_gradient_descent(var_list[i].handle, l_r, grads[i], use_locking=self._use_locking)
            opsR.append(opt1)


        return opsR
```

With this commented out, it trains, but there is no collaboration. I've tried a couple other things, and they all either don't run or don't train.

Comment: Why not create a custom optimizer, instead of a separate function for this? You can check the documentation for details on how to do it, and you can have a higher degree of integration with the rest of your code.

Comment: Oh, I didn't specify that this is within an Optimizer subclass